# What should I learn to become a good web developer?

Tags: zend-framework, node.js, symfony1

I'm coding in PHP since a long time. And since a few days I've been looking for a job in web development.

Apparently they're looking for people who either knows ZEND or Symfony. I don't know either one (although I did work a bit on CodeIgniter).

And I really wanted to get into node.js these days.

So I'm asking you guys, what should I privilege to get a job? I have a feeling Node.js is going to become something really important and demanded, so I'd better get into it before others do...

What do you think? Are there other things out there I should learn? I really don't want to get into RoR since I do PHP.

Comment: Its not so much which platform you should learn, but that you keep learning and stay current.

Comment: I like this idea, although I'm not studying IT and I don't have THAT MUCH time to put into it so I have to chose unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a highly contested topic, but node.js is more of a buzzword than anything and it will not be a skill established companies are looking for.  Many people have realized that javascript is far too nuanced to efficiently write large-scale applications, and that doesn't change once it's server-side.  If you want job prospects, learn a statically-typed, managed language like Java or C#.  These are not trendy, and for that reason a lot of people will tell me I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with the Node.js suggestion but would also learn the jQuery and jQuery mobile libraries for JavaScript.

They offer a huge amount of functions to ease web development along with support for HTML5 functionality. The other nice thing about this is you can write mobile web apps using jQuery mobile and support all platforms (iOS, Android, WP) with one app. It won't be native but it can still be a great looking app with a huge amount of functionality.

EDIT: Definitely agree with everything Breland says and in addition I'd like to emphasize that SQLite on the client-side would be something good to learn. It's a really nice feature where you can create a client-side database if you want to persist data that is a too big for a cookie or you can go with a real database. 
Unfortunately AFAIK it's only supported on webkit browsers right now (Safari, Chrome, Android, iOS) but it could be good to learn how to use this and also an ORM like persistencejs which is a jQuery plugin that creates an ORM for SQLite and can work on the client or server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Agree, Node.js and jQuery are going to be the big winners here; for client side development anyway. Also, ensure you're well versed in CSS (especially CSS3) and are familiar with HTML(5) and how all of these work together to make beautiful web apps.

As far as server side development goes, you're really free to choose whatever, after all, it's rare the client ever sees the actual code that makes a WebService run. If you can make a reliable WebService in PHP, sure. C#? Why not? RoR? Java? Python? The more you know, the more marketable you are, and you get exposed to a lot more code. Personally, just because I'm forced into the big business world, C# is what I use almost exclusively, but only because I use it everyday.

If you get super adventurous, go for some understanding of SQL as well. And network setup etc. But that could be out of the scope of a web developer.

Answer (score 1):

These days, a "Web Developer" means something else than what it used to 3 or 4 years ago. That skill set is further split into disciplines now, mainly front-end and back-end. The path you go with will likely be based on what you've been comfortable doing as a PHP developer.

1. If you've been building PHP apps the "traditional" way and controlling all aspects of your MVC apps through PHP then learning modern PHP frameworks that make that approach easier  would be an easy next step.
2. If you've been building PHP backends that expose business logic through an API or service layer, you can stick to the backend track and learn to do the same in Ruby on Rails (using something like rails-api) or Node.js if you wish. If you go the node.js route, picking up CoffeeScript will make writing your JavaScript a little more comfortable but it's another syntax you'll have to learn.

If you've done both 1 and 2 above and you like client side development, learn modern Javascript web development. Don't worry too much about which framework to side with yet, just learn the modern way of building large JS apps. A book I recommend for that is JavaScript Web Applications by Alex McCaw (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018421.do). It did wonders to help me shed my dislike of JavaScript which came from working with the language many moons ago.

My advice would be to learn both sides of the fence and master one or two frameworks on each side. That will make you what's now called a "full stack" developer, which is just a term used to identify those who are effective at client and backend dev thereby making them highly desirable in the marketplace.

Good luck.